# Desktop icon position (programmatically access and manipulate)

Tags: gnome, bash, nautilus, gvfs

I'd like to programmatically access and manipulate the Desktop icon positions, their icons, etc.

This is for files and directories that you keep in ~/Desktop .

Where is this stuff stored?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Stored as GVFS metadata attributes.

To get all GVFS metadata attributes for file/directory:

```
gvfs-info '/home/user/Desktop/Untitled Folder/'
```

To get specific attribute - icon position:

```
gvfs-info -a 'metadata::nautilus-icon-position' '/home/user/Desktop/Untitled Document/'
```

To set icon position:

```
gvfs-set-attribute -t string '/home/user/Desktop/Untitled Document/' 'metadata::nautilus-icon-position' '500,500'
```

Remember to refresh desktop (F5 key) to see effect.

If lower level manipulation required there is Nautilus Extension API (via libnautilus):

https://developer.gnome.org/libnautilus-extension/stable/

and specifically:

https://developer.gnome.org/libnautilus-extension/stable/NautilusFileInfo.html

Comment: This works well for actual files; is it also possible to access `metadata::nautilus-icon-position` for the special icons that appear on the desktop for USB drives, ‘Home’, etc? `gvfs-info -a 'metadata::nautilus-icon-position' '/home/user/Desktop/External-drive'` says “No such file or directory”.

Comment: The commands are now `gio info` and `gio set`, for example on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: With the gio utility:

To get all metadata attributes for file/directory:

`gio info  '/home/user/Desktop/Untitled Folder/'`

To set icon position:

`gio set --type=string  '/home/user/Desktop/Untitled Folder/' 'metadata::nautilus-icon-position' '500,500'`